# python: Optimise groups of similar products for similarity in groups and for similarity over groups collectively?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, similarity, maximize

I have a dataframe/table of product data that contains all possible pairings of products in the format:

- origin product
- destination product
- similarity of the two products (Jaccard index)

Using this similarity data, I would like to use Python to group each product into groups of similar products. I would like to optimise these groups using some optimisation algorithm (or similar device) to maximise the mean similarity of each group and of the universe of groups as a whole.
I likely also need to account for group size in some way as I don't want a small number of huge groups or lots of really tiny groups.

For example

| Origin | destination | Similarity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| prod 1 | prod 2 | 1 |
| prod 3 | prod 2 | 6 |
| prod 1 | prod 3 | 1 |
| prod 1 | prod 4 | 2 |
| prod 3 | prod 4 | 1 |
| prod 2 | prod 4 | 1 |
| prod 1 | prod 5 | 4 |
| prod 3 | prod 5 | 0 |
| prod 2 | prod 5 | 1 |
| prod 5 | prod 4 | 3 |

Groups:

**Group A = mean similarity of 3**
products 1, 4, and 5

**Group B = mean similarity of 6**
products 2 and 3

**Universe = mean similarity of 4.5**

I've attempted quite a few methods already but all very manual and not particularly repeatable or scalable.

Would anyone be able to suggest any optimisation algorithms for this problem with examples/documentation for how to implement them in Python?

I don't have any experience in optimisation algorithms or statistical testing in this sense either, so if anyone has any suggestions for better metrics than mean similarity etc., then please do let me know. Looking to learn as much as I can :)

Thank you!

**Previous attempts:**

I tried iterating over the unique products and creating subsets of the dataframe where that product is the origin product.

I then applied the current group of each destination product to the dataframe and grouped up by current group value.

I then assigned each unique product to the group that had the highest mean similarity value or if it didn't meet a certain threshold, I allowed it to create a new group.

However, this didn't really optimise the groups once they were assigned, even when i iterated through it multiple times.

I think the limitation of it was that it only looked at one product at a time and the only optimisation was for that product into a new group. It didn't look at how that move affected the current group or how it affected the strength of the universe of groups overall.

Comment: Hi! Perhaps [scikit-learn 's tutorial on clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) could be useful to you.

Comment: And if you really cannot find a suitable clustering algorithm in scikit-learn, then you could try scikit-learn-extra: [sklearn_extra.cluster.KMedoids](https://scikit-learn-extra.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/sklearn_extra.cluster.KMedoids.html) (but I do recommend looking at scikit-learn first)

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the title of the question to make it easier to read, in particular by removing the two occurrences of "strength of". Feel free to unroll the edit if you preferred your title before my edit.

Comment: @Stef thanks for your comment, do you have any recommendations for a suitable clustering algorithm from those suggested? They all seem very similar to me (no experience in clustering), so not really sure which would be the best for my problem, thanks

Comment: If you only have the pairwise distances (or pairwise similarities) then you should choose the only one in their table which has "any pairwise distance" in the rightmost column. The other ones require your distances to correspond to geometric distances, ie the products should be like points in a geometric space.

Comment: But if you actually have access to the values of the features that allowed you to compute the similarities, then other algorithms might be better.

Comment: Also look at the "parameters" column on the left. These "parameters" are the information that you will keep control on, ie, the information that you have to feed the algorithm. For instance, algorithms that have "number of clusters" as a parameter are algorithms where **you** have to tell the algorithm how many groups you want (as opposed to the algorithm figuring out an optimal number of clusters by itself)

Comment: Thank you. The original data set includes each sale of a product and who bought it. The similarity calculation is just the total intersection of customers that bought both products divided by the total sales of both products. The aim of this is to group similar products together into categories based on the sales data and the similarity calculation is an attempt to reduce the bias towards high selling products that would sway too much one way if just using an intersection value for similarity.

Comment: Also the algorithms that say "hierarchical" are not just building clusters, but trees (where the products are leaves of the tree) where every tree node can be considered a cluster